# REST API in Tizen Wearable SDK

Tags: rest, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

Does Tizen Wearable SDK provide REST API support to collect data from any server using URL? Or do I need to collect the desired data from the mobile application first and then pass the data to the Wearable device running Tizen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, only a bluetooth connection to the host device is allowed, hence, you'd have to make all REST calls on the host app and relay the results to the gear client app.

Comment: Check Samsung Accessory Protocol

Answer (score 2):

On Samsung Tizen IDE 2.4 there are an Web Aplication example (Online Sample Tab) named "NewsFeed" that get information on XML format from internet using XMLHttpRequest and it is for a Samsung wearable.

Answer (score -1):

On Samsung Gear S you have available internet connection and you can use external APIs like REST.

To get data from external services  you can use standard  XMLHttpRequest object. https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/XMLHttpRequest or if you using jQuery you can use $.get or $.post methods.